# What's the benefit of manual bootstrapping in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm about to start a big project in angular and I want to bootstrap multiple applications manually. I've read a ton of blog posts and angular documentation (I hope I didn't miss the ones that explain why), and the only benefits of manual bootstrapping are:

- you can perform an initial request that will provide you with data required for starting your app (e.g. translations).
- you can have multiple apps inside the same web page (due to the nature of auto-bootstrapping).

---

**Questions**

- Am I missing any something?
- Does anyone see any other benefit?
- Should I use manual bootstrapping?

Comment: you could read here : https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data

Comment: It depends what you need. If you have module loaders like RequireJS, then you would need manual bootstraping. Or if you have multiple apps on the page.

Comment: @cesarandavisa this is one of the posts I've read, and he is leveraging manual bootstrapping for loading data before the application starts.

Comment: @dfsq yes RequireJS will be used, but this falls into the 2nd point where you might have multiple apps. Right?